# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: phpmyadmin

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()
> expects parameter 2 to be resource,
> boolean given in
> /var/www/login/data/www/site.ru/lib/DbSimple/Mysql.php
> on line 57
>
> Warning: mysql_error() expects
> parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
> given in
> /var/www/login/data/www/site.ru/lib/DbSimple/Mysql.php
> on line 194

Что за ошибка? Знает кто?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь впихнуть невпихуемое. Вот, что она значит.  
Ожидается на входе ресурс, а вы булево значение подсовываете.  
Код покажите свой.

Comment: извините какой код не понял?

Comment: php-код. Хотя, судя по всему, у вас не устанавливается соединение с базой данных. Проверьте подключение.

Answer (score 2):

Ну разве сложно посмотреть в переводчике? Ожидается тип Ресурс, а вы передали булевский

Comment: а что означает "булевский"?

Comment: Логический. Грубо говоря, в вашем случае функция ждет на вход строку, а ей на вход логическое значение **false** передается.

Answer (score 0):

Код в студию, вы передаете ф-и boolean, а нужно передать хендл соединения (хотя можно вообще не передавать, тогда по умолчанию будет использовано последнее открытое с помощью mysql_connect()). mysql_connect() кстати вернет false в случае неудачи, а вы не проверили соединение в коде. Исправить можно так:

```
<?php
...
$link = mysql_connect(/*параметры*/) or die("Ошибка подключения");
...
$escaped_string = mysql_real_escape_string($string, $link);
...
echo mysql_error($link);
?>
```

Теперь в $link точно не будет false просто скрипт будет вылетать с ошибкой

Comment: Да еще одно: почему вы так упорно налегаете на устаревший технически и морально mysql. 2014 год на дворе, пора уже PDO (mysqli) юзать!